# "Object not found" error in gls

Tags: spss, r

As the R very beginner I'd like to ask if anyone could help me with the following problem?

```
library(foreign)
reg1 <- read.spss("URL of the spss file")
library(nlme)
model1 <- gls(v1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, correlation=corARMA(p=1), data=reg1)
```

**Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'v1' not found**

All the variables v1 to x6 are present in the spss file. Thanks in advance for help.

Thanks Nick. I can't share the file. I tried the procedure, but I got the similar result:

> library(foreign)
>
> library(nlme)
>
> reg1 <- read.spss("URL", to.data.frame=TRUE)
>
> class(reg1) #check that it is indeed a data.frame 
>   [1] "data.frame"
>
> colnames(reg1) #check that all column names are properly imported 
>   ....

[17] "x1"            "x2"            "x3"            "x4"
 [21] "x5"            "x6"

....

[97] "...."          "v1"            "...."          "...."

....

> model1 <- gls(v1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, correlation=corARMA(p=1), data=reg1)

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'img4' not found

Comment: The error has indeed changed (v1 -> img4). It is not clear where this last error comes from, but: re-run your code, and right after you get the error, run traceback(). This might give you/us a hint on what's wrong (as it displays the call stack at the time of the error).

Comment: Well, actually I've 'debranded' the variables' names (so as the brands were impossible to identify). img4 is not a brand, but I also substituted the name of this variable for v1 writing my post. I just forgot to change it in the message about error. So, basically, the error has not changed.

Comment: It may be better to either show the _actual_ code you ran, to avoid these kinds of confusions (all too often, an assumption during the 'translation' turns out to be the real culprit). Either way: I cannot debug this since I can't run it, so your only option is to use the traceback, or do actual debugging.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation of `?gls`:
`data: an optional data frame`

In relation, the documentation of `?read.spss` shows a parameter `to.data.frame`, whose default is `FALSE`, so typically `reg1` will be a list instead of a `data.frame`.

The code you provided is not useful for testing on my system (as you do not provide the actual dataset), but this will probably work (disregarding library statements):

```
reg1 <- read.spss("URL of the spss file", to.data.frame=TRUE)
class(reg1) #check that it is indeed a data.frame
colnames(reg1) #check that all column names are properly imported
model1 <- gls(v1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, correlation=corARMA(p=1), data=reg1)
```